# PHP echo mysqli data table from the last

Tags: php, mysql

i need help.. im trying to echo all the data from my database but from the last to the first.
im a college student and i need ur help.

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($i < 6)) { // my lecture ask me to echo 5 data only
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) { 
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";  
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
```

that is my code for now, and its only echoing from the first table to the last. my lecture told me i need to echo from the last.

edit :
i think i haven't give all the information.. sorry, this is the first time im here :(.

```
<?php 

    $i = 1;
    include_once("function/helper.php");
    include_once("function/koneksi.php");

    $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM transaksi ");

    $pemilik = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


?>

<?php

$i = 1;
$sql = "SELECT mutasi, waktu_tanggal,tujuan FROM transaksi WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY waktu_tanggal";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    ?>
    <h1>Anda belum melakukan transaksi apapun</h1>
    <?php
}else {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <th>Mutasi</th>

        <th>Waktu</th>
        <th>Keterangan</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($i < 6)) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {  line like this: foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

that is the entire page.

Comment: The fix would not be in your code here, but in your query. As shown in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), you can use `ORDER BY` to change the order of your results.

Comment: Add your query to the question i.e. the one that has `SELECT * FROM ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;
```

The sql [ORDER BY] command is used to sort the result set in ascending or descending order.

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table_name ORDER BY column1 DESC;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try php function mysqli_fetch_all () --- >> you don't need a while-loop.
Then create a new array and populate it with the required number of records.

Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 5*FROM `MyTable`";
// Or alternative query: "SELECT*FROM `MyTable LIMIT 5`

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

   if($result != 0) {
      $newDataArray = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
   }
```

Comment: ok,, im going to research this function.thanks for replying sir